# Explicitly set panel size (not just plot size) in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to explicitly set the panel size (i.e., the gray grid panel) in a ggplot? I imagine (but can't find) that there is some ggplot extension that allows for arguments that resemble `panel.width = unit(3, "in"), panel.height = unit(4, "in")`.

I have seen solutions for setting the size of the entire plot, or of getting multiple plots to align using the `egg` package. But nothing that would let me explicitly set the size of the panel.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

ds_mt <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("model")
mt_short <- ds_mt %>% arrange(nchar(model)) %>% slice(1:4)
mt_long <- ds_mt %>% arrange(-nchar(model)) %>% slice(1:4)

p_short <- 
    mt_short %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = model, y = mpg)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    coord_flip()

p_short
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `ggsave`?

Comment: @jan-glx, ggsave() can set the dimensions of the entire plot, but I am trying to control the dimensions of the panel within the plot.

Comment: And by `panel` you mean the area that is usually grey?

Comment: @jan-glx yes, and thank you for clarifying, I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: I knew that if someone would have [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32583612/1870254) it would be @baptiste.

Comment: Can you provide a visual of desired result? This may involve using image software (Paint, Paintbrush, Pinta, etc.)

Comment: Following @jan-glx link I found that I can use p1 <- set_panel_size(p_short, width = unit(4, "cm"), height = unit(4,  "cm")) in combo with grid.arrange(p1) to set panel size explicitly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `set_panel_size()` function from the [egg](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/) package

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ds_mt <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("model")
mt_short <- ds_mt %>% arrange(nchar(model)) %>% slice(1:4)
mt_long <- ds_mt %>% arrange(-nchar(model)) %>% slice(1:4)

p_short <- 
  mt_short %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = model, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  coord_flip()

library(egg)
library(grid)
p_fixed <- set_panel_size(p_short,
                          width  = unit(10, "cm"),
                          height = unit(4, "in"))
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(p_fixed)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Answer (score 19):

The ggh4x package has a [similar function](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html#sizes-1) to the egg solution presented in the other answer. A slight convenience is that the plot is still a valid ggplot after using the function, so it would work with `ggsave()` and other layers can be added afterwards. (disclaimer: I wrote ggh4x)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(ggh4x)

ds_mt <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("model")
mt_short <- ds_mt %>% arrange(nchar(model)) %>% slice(1:4)
mt_long <- ds_mt %>% arrange(-nchar(model)) %>% slice(1:4)

mt_short %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = model, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  coord_flip() +
  force_panelsizes(rows = unit(4, "in"),
                   cols = unit(3, "in"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: it's like the ggh4x package is becoming a solution for almost all unsolved ggplot problems :)

Comment: well that might be because ggh4x is my outlet for solving my own ggplot problems :p

Comment: I like this one because it works with `ggsave`

Comment: ggh4x is such a great resource, thank you very much!