# ggplot2, arrange multiple plots, all the same size, no gaps in between

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to arrange multiple plots into one figure, without any gaps between the plot area, and all plots being exactly the same size (see image below for a sketch of my desired figure, which comprises 6 individual plots).

[image: desired figure, composed of 6 individual plots]

I have tried `ggarrange` (ggpubr) and `plot_grid` (cowplot) and a couple others but they seem to have the same problem - you can align the plots to get them the same size, but not arrange them closer to each other.

`ggdraw` in the cowplot package allows one to specify exactly where the plots go, but they are all slightly different sizes.

Is there a way to overcome this?

Basically, I want to make the plot area (where the data is displayed, **NOT** the axes and labels) the same for six graphs, then arrange them contiguously.  So far I have not found anyway to do this.

The x-axis variable is the same for all 6 graphs, but the y is different, and there are multiple series on some of the graphs but not others, so I cannot use the facet option in ggplot2.

Please help!

EDIT: Sorry, some more info - because my plots have different y variables, the plot margins and the plot panels are all slightly different sizes.  So that means when I try to add them all together, they are out of alignment.
[Plots different sizes out of alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUMGl.png).  plot_grid from cowplot allows you to specify position, and size, BUT, the size is the size of the whole plot, panel and margins included.  Because of the Y-axis labels, the margins are different sizes, and resizing them using the arguments to plot_grid is not so simple.

Comment: Have you seen these questions? Unsure if they're duplicates, but they might help: [reduce space between grid.arrange plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299496/reduce-space-between-grid-arrange-plots), and [Side-by-side plots with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1249548/8366499)

Comment: `cowplot::draw_plot` lets you specify position, height and width.

Comment: I use **library(gridExtra)** to combine plots - works perfectly. Specify **layout <- rbind(c(1, 1, 1), c(2, 2, 2))** and use  **grid.arrange(p1, p2, layout_matrix = layout)** AND for p1 and p2 (two ggplots) add **theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"cm"))**
to control space between two plots

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Side-by-side plots with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249548/side-by-side-plots-with-ggplot2)

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  None of the options were quite what I was looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249548/side-by-side-plots-with-ggplot2 still leaves some gaps between the plots, and I need the gaps gone completely.  This one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299496/reduce-space-between-grid-arrange-plots I don't even understand how to use, being relatively new to R.

Comment: @Annaz that seems to only work if the plot panels are already the same size, otherwise it results in a painstaking process of a multitude of axis adjustments trying to get the panels the same size.

Answer (score 3):

So I managed to find an answer, based on some code from here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-do-i-control-the-size-of-the-panel-in-a-ggplot-so-they-are-consistent/14377/8

The plots first need to be passed through the     `align_plots()`     function in 
    `cowplot()`    , to make a list of the plots:

```
`multiplot <- align_plots(plotAA,plotBB,plotCC,plotDD,plotEE,plotFF, align = "hv")`
```

Then the panels of the graphs will be all the same size, and they can be arranged using 
    `ggdraw()`     and     `draw_plot()`     as follows:

```
`ggdraw() + draw_grob(multiplot[[1]], 0,0.565,.6,.4) +
  draw_grob(multiplot[[2]], 0.396,0.565,0.6,0.4) + 
  draw_grob(multiplot[[3]], 0, 0.285, 0.6,0.4) +
  draw_grob(multiplot[[4]], 0.396, 0.285, 0.6, 0.4) +
  draw_grob(multiplot[[5]], 0,0.004, 0.6, 0.4) +
  draw_grob(multiplot[[6]], 0.396,0.004,0.6,0.4)`
```

to give the final figure:
[Desired plot arrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMmcV.png)

I hope this helps somebody else in the future,
Thanks.

Comment: EDIT: that should be the 'draw_plot()' function in place of 'draw_grob()' (though either works).

Comment: 2nd Edit: the first thing I would do is make the panel and plot backgrounds transparent using `theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour=NA, fill = "transparent"), plot.background = element_rect(colour=NA, fill = "transparent"))`.  Then it is easier to position the graphs correctly.