# How to arrange `ggplot2` objects side-by-side and ensure equal plotting areas?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, gridextra

I am trying to arrange two `ggplot2` plots side by side, i.e., in a two-column
layout using the package `gridExtra`. I am interested in ensuring that both
plots have equal plotting area (i.e., the gray plot panel is the same for both
plots) regardless of the height of the x-axis labels. As you can see in the
example below, when longer x-axis labels are used, `gridExtra::grid.arrange()`
seems to compensate this by adjusting the plotting area (i.e., the grayed out
part of the plot).

```r
# Dummy data.
data <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10))

# Dummy labels.
x_labels_short <- 1:10
x_labels_long <- 100001:100010

# Common settings for both `ggplot2` plots.
layers <- list(
    labs(
        x = "Plot title"
    ),
    theme(
        axis.text.x = element_text(
            angle = 90,
            vjust = 0.5,
            hjust = 1
        )
    )
)

# `ggplot2 plot (a).
plot_a <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10, labels = x_labels_short) +
    layers

# `ggplo2` plot (b).
plot_b <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10, labels = x_labels_long) +
    layers

# Showing the plots side by side.
gridExtra::grid.arrange(
    plot_a,
    plot_b,
    ncol = 2
)
```

**Output:**

[image: ggplot2 plot]

What I want is for both plots to (1) have equal plotting area and (b) the x-axis
title of `plot_a` to be aligned with that of `plot_b` (i.e., the x-axis title of
`plot_a` to be offset based on the length of of the x-axis labels of `plot_b`).

If this is not clear, this is what I want to achieve would look like with base
`R`.

```r
# Wrapper for convenience.
plot_gen <- function(data, labels) {
    plot(
        NULL,
        xlim = c(1, 10),
        ylim = c(min(data$y), max(data$y)),
        xlab = "",
        ylab = "y",
        xaxt = "n"
    )
    axis(
        side = 1,
        at = 1:10,
        labels = labels,
        las = 2
    )
    title(
        xlab = "Plot title",
        line = 4.5
    )
}

# Get `par`.
old_par = par(no.readonly = TRUE)

# Set the two-column layout.
layout(matrix(1:2, ncol = 2))

# Adjust margins.
par(mar = old_par$mar + c(1.5, 0, 0, 0))

# Plot base plot one.
plot_gen(data, x_labels_short)

# Plot base plot two.
plot_gen(data, x_labels_long)

# Restore `par`.
par(old_par)

# Restore layout.
layout(1:1)
```

**Output:**

[image: base R plot]

Quick mention. I found a similar question on SO (i.e.,
[How to specify the size of a graph in ggplot2 independent of axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46840724/5252007)), however I fail to see how the
answers address the problem. Also, the plots I am trying to arrange are based
on different data and I don't think I can use a `facet_wrap` approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One suggestion: the `patchwork` package.

```r
library(patchwork)
plot_a + plot_b
```

[image: ggplot side-by-side with similar axis spacing]

It also works for more complex layouts, e.g.:

```r
(plot_a | plot_b) / plot_a
```

[image]

Comment: What if I have a more complex layout, say, one plot that spans two columns above `plot_a` and `plot_b`?

Comment: I looked it up and it seems to do the trick `(plot_a | plot_b) / plot_a`! Are you also aware of a solution without relaying on other packages than `ggplot2`?

Comment: I'm glad you found the layout trick. Layout control with `ggplot2`-derived plots can get rather difficult to do well, correctly, and robustly, as you have determined. The `patchwork` package brings in no more (non-base) dependencies other than what `ggplot2` already does. While I appreciate your intent to reduce package-clutter ... this problem is hard to do well. I strongly suggest including this package.

Comment: You hinted well at my attempt to reduce package-clutter. I took a look at the GitHub repository and I was impressed with the expressive API of the package. I will take your advice and switch to `patchwork`. Thanks for the quick and clean solution---you saved me hours.

Comment: A useless comment, but I can't resist it. I've been using `patchwork` for about a month now, and it's absolutely brilliant! Thanks for suggesting it, @r2evans.